# How to apply a custom pipe to filter in Angular 5

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm working on a MEAN Stack app, what i'm trying to do is showing all users then when the user typing in the `input` filed it filter the users

this is the custom pipe that i create

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(){}

  transform( users: any, term: any ): any {
    if(term === undefined) return users;
    return users.filter(function(user){
      return user.username.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
  }

}
```

All i did was importing the pipe in `component.ts`

```
import { FilterPipe } from '../../filter.pipe';
```

And in the component.html I add the `input` filed that the user will write inside it to filter the users

```
<div class="inputWithIcon">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." [(ngModel)]="term" >
      <i class="fa fa-search fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </form>
  </div>
```

then i add the `ngFor`

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <li  *ngFor="let user of userData | filter:term" class="list-group-item" >
          <a [routerLink]="['/my-courses/', user.username]" >{{ user.username }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

but that didn't worked

Comment: that the pipe didn't work

Comment: check this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twws3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I even copied your code but that didn't work maybe because the data came from the Data Base

Comment: now what is the issue? data not showing on ui?